# git commit without environment author

Tags: git

Please spare me the lecture on how this is a bad practice... I know, but it is a money issue.

We have multiple people who have to use a single computer as needed for a certain project.  I want them to always be forced to specify the `--author=` when committing, so I do NOT want to have an environment variable set up which would allow them to "forget".

However, it seems `--author=` will only override environment variables, so it can not be used when one is not set.

Is there a way I can either set environment variables that will fail when one tries to commit with them, or another method which I can use to force them to add the switch?

If all else fails, I will write my own "git" override script that asks for the author from user input, but I was hoping for something cleaner.

A similar question was asked here:
[Git specify user and e-mail on commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591982/git-specify-user-and-e-mail-on-commit)

But it never was answered satisfactorily.

Comment: Is allowing them to use different users on said computer not an option? Wouldn't that allow them to have distinct git user configurations?

Comment: While it IS an option, it's WAY easier not to.  I'd rather not have maintain different user accounts :/

Comment: `Please spare me the lecture on how this is a bad practice... I know, but it is a money issue.` This is great  Also, I'm sorry you had to deal with this. Also, I think your idea of writing a custom script is your best bet, hopefully this worked out well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below code from **.git/config** and it will prompt you for username and password every time.

```
[credential]
    helper = store
    # or helper=cache
```

Comment: I'm not pushing, just committing.  So I don't need a username and password, just Author.

Answer (score -1):

I found a link which might help you with changing author name for old commits.
[Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042437/change-commit-author-at-one-specific-commit)

Comment: While this is helpful, It has nothing to do with my question.